# Wildcard ##any error xml schema validation

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-validation

Getting the error above while validating the XSD against the schema in C#. Schema looks for the listed tags and other tags coming in are optional. 
Below is my XSD file. How the xml file will need to modified so it makes sure it has those tags listed below in XSD and ignores extra tags.it is using the XML text reader to do the schema validation

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="InvoiceExport" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="InvoiceExport" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Invoice">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Invoice_ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />             
              <xs:element name="BillingEntity" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                  
                    <xs:element name="VendorNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                                        
                    <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceBaseInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="InvoiceDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                  
                    <xs:element name="BillingEntityInvoiceNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                    
                    <xs:element name="ReceivedDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                   
                    <xs:element name="AdjustedBilledAmount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                    
                    <xs:element name="UserFields" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                          <xs:element name="FirstApproverID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="LastApproverID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="LegalSpendCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:all>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                     <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceMatter" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>                       
                    <xs:element name="Priority_CD" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                   
                    <xs:element name="InvoiceMatterDetail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>                        
                          <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="InvoiceMatterAllocation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>                          
                          <xs:element name="AllocationAmount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="ChargeBackAccount1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="ChargeBackAccount2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="ChargeBackAccount3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="UserFields" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="InvoiceMatterApproval" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">                   
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="EmployeeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />                          
                          <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>         
              <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Change the Occurs property in the schema : minOccurs="1"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your schema allows any number of elements called InvoiceMatter, followed by an element which can have any name (including the name InvoiceMatter); so if an InvoiceMatter element is found then it's ambiguous whether it matches the specific element particle or the wildcard.

XSD 1.1 solves this by saying that the specific element particle always takes precedence, so one solution is simply to use an XSD 1.1 processor (such as Saxon).

If you can't do that the usual XSD 1.0 solution is to use a targetNamespace attribute on the xs:any wildcard to restrict it by namespace (e.g. `targetNamespace="##other"`). But that's a change to your design; if you want to allow elements in the same namespace, then you've got a problem.